# Lexus RX 3500 2007 wet floor driver’s side

Tags: leak, hvac, lexus, water-leak, lexus-rx

The floor in my Lexus RX 3500 2007 is very wet for some reason (on the picture it’s already dry).[image]

Does anybody know what could be a reason?

Comment: Does your lexus have a sunroof? If so, I'm wondering if one (or both) of the drains is/are plugged.

Comment: Has it been out in the rain?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes I have sunroof and it looks like those drains have been clogged but I am surprised how water could reach those drains because my sunroof was completely closed

Comment: @HandyHowie yeah it was under rain

Comment: Some water will get past the seal on the sunroof.  The drains are there to collect the water that gets past the seal.  If the drains are blocked, the water will find another way out, which it appears to be doing.  The final destination being your carpet.  I would suggest making sure those drain pipes are clear.

Comment: @HandyHowie I see thx. Do I need to remove the carpet and dry it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is, one (or both) of the sunroof drains are plugged up, causing water to overflow into the cabin during rain. You can easily test it by retracting the sunroof and pouring a little bit of water into the track near the drain. There are usually two drains located at the front corners. If you pour the water in there and it stays stagnant, the drain is plugged. You might also already see either a small amount of water there already or the traces of where the water line was at.

If it is plugged, use a long, pliable wire and run it down the entrance to the drain. You want to be careful doing this, because you run the possibility of poking through the tubing which makes up the drain. If you bend the end of the wire over into a small loop (like a teardrop), it will make it so it is less likely to do any damage. You'll still want to be careful. If there is a small amount of water in the drain area when you do this, you'll very easily notice when the blockage is cleared as the excess water will quickly drain out.

As an aside, the reason I come to the conclusion why this may be your drain(s) is because the area you are pointing out is a typical place where water is found when the drain gets plugged. If this was the passenger side, it could just as easily be the AC drain which is plugged, but you would usually only see it get wet there during summer months when the AC is running all the time.

Comment: I find that the plastic cord that you use for cutting grass in a strimmer is good for poking down drain tubes.  It is very unlikely to damage anything including scratching paint off any metal parts.

Comment: @HandyHowie - That is a very good idea, one I'd never thought of. Thanks for the awesome tip!

Comment: I cleaned the drains, thanks. 
Also after I used heater or AC I could see some condensation water under my car when parking. But recently I noticed there is no water under my car, could it be water goes inside instead?

Comment: @user25963 - There will only be water on the ground under the AC drain if there is humidity in the air enough to cause it to condensate during AC usage. Also, you actually have to be using your AC in order for it to condensate. Usually in winter months, the humidity goes down and even if using the defroster (with which the AC compressor runs), there's not enough there to cause condensation to cause it to drip.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thx, follow-up question: is it necessary to remove the carpet and dry it from underneath?

Comment: @user25963 - That would be up to you and how wet it has gotten. You could try using an vacuum which can extract water. I've not had problems with thing mildewing from what you're talking about, however, rust is something to consider.

Comment: It would be worth checking the drains for the AC.  There are usually 2 open tubes directly under the dashboard accessible from under the vehicle.